# SwiftData - Assignment randomly failing

Tags: swift-data

I have a SwiftData class which has an attribute of

```
var dimObject : DIM?
```

I'm trying to assign a DIM object to that attribute, buts its randomly failing with

> > Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8000000000000010)

Its never the same object, nor do I get any further indications of what's causing it.

I've narrowed it down to

```
digimon.dimObject = dimFound
```

in the below function

```
    func insertDigimon(digimon: Digimon) {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    if let dimFound = getDIMFromID(dimID: digimon.dim) {
        print("****************************************************************")
        print("Digimon: \(digimon.name) - ID: \(digimon.id)")
        print("DIM: \(dimFound.name)")
        print("Set DIM Object on Digimon")
        digimon.dimObject = dimFound
        print("Digimon object set")
        print("Add digimon to DIM")
        dimFound.addToDigimon(d: digimon)
        print("Digimon added to DIM")
    }
    modelContext.insert(digimon)
}
```

If I comment out that line, there's no error

Both the digimon and dimFound objects aren't nil and contain the expected object.

Links to full classes

DIM: https://pastebin.com/0k4Tez7c

Digimon: https://pastebin.com/iyP06JZX

List View: https://pastebin.com/nWput7Bd

Comment: What does `dimFound.addToDigimon(d: digimon)` do? Is it what I expect and update the relationship property?

Comment: The dim model has a property call Digimon, which is either an nsset, or [Digimon]. Can’t remember of the top of my head. That function appends the Digimon to that property. 

The command seems to work fine, it’s the previous one that’s failing. Adding the dim to the Digimon

Comment: So it's not a SwiftData relationship then? Could you please post enough code so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've added links to the full classes